# How copy request body, headers (without tags) from log cat in android studio when using Retrofit(Okhttp)?

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2, logcat, okhttp

I am unable to copy only request body (without tags) from log cat. I think it is very useful feature, because you often need to check request via postman, and it is hard making another similar request(especially if request is signed digitally). Here is log example which i want to copy without D: prefix:

```
D: --> POST http://url
D: Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
D: Content-Length: 3586
D: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><APRequest>
D: <jsonString>{"searchDate":"24.01.2019","userOrgCode":"19710003","userId":"5000000000014720"}</jsonString>
D: <dateOfSend>1548316774835</dateOfSend>
D: <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
D: <ds:SignedInfo>
D: <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
D: <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
D: <ds:Reference URI="">
D: <ds:Transforms>
D: <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
D: <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
D: </ds:Transforms>
D: <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
D: <ds:DigestValue>KK5lQsy9CqracgR1YS2nZBkY2gU4ntOCtAgbPQeI7AU=</ds:DigestValue>
D: </ds:Reference>
D: </ds:SignedInfo>
D: <ds:SignatureValue>
D: T1CWxz0kgoKKFFwCBaA+oOfMunnzjF4fZEWoB5ll+Sdm6ql/mcHtJUEcVVF2MgwzYVP9O0TI5iiD
D: VGg9in36dC6WcCqb9UmNJM/I8KM1CDszwAWHLSto7dgSlE1DgXlImI2DhexcrXQyMyXVboQOPrHO
D: qbtT1Ou8hL+M8j/jxe5HMyANH55/3x83/8aae5GBxAVsaCyfJR5wWe4FXdDBRHU65RFe/JxRrDo3
D: 3sqed8P0AMtDPJwqKv3gm7y4i5sPpoRpaMTPBhKKqkZyFLT7TCVEoTbFJ1z9d7SWakTRsGNsQhr6
D: sGJ9gniyjq/J9Qw/LdC4muCQ9I6t/OJhZSW+Fg==
D: </ds:SignatureValue>
D: <ds:KeyInfo>
D: <ds:X509Data>
D: <ds:X509Certificate>
D: MIIGZTCCBE2gAwIBAgIUIH2IhoiQPOeoZt1XwaQWoelFpIAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwUjELMAkG
D: A1UEBhMCS1oxQzBBBgNVBAMMOtKw0JvQotCi0KvSmiDQmtCj05jQm9CQ0J3QlNCr0KDQo9Co0Ksg
D: 0J7QoNCi0JDQm9Cr0pogKFJTQSkwHhcNMTgxMTEyMDU0MjUwWhcNMTkxMTEyMDU0MjUwWjCBpzEc
D: MBoGA1UEAwwT0JDQodKa0JDQoCDTmNCh0JXQojETMBEGA1UEBAwK0JDQodKa0JDQoDEYMBYGA1UE
D: BRMPSUlOOTUwMzMxMzAwMzI0MQswCQYDVQQGEwJLWjEVMBMGA1UEBwwM0JDQodCi0JDQndCQMRUw
D: EwYDVQQIDAzQkNCh0KLQkNCd0JAxHTAbBgNVBCoMFNKa0JDQm9CY0JHQldCa0rDQm9CrMIIBIjAN
D: BgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAqQkJDPEj5sbIme7Qw9rpOTTVU6CG1ZVQgR/Ll9d1
D: gVtd++ZYN2uirrBhFFAGR9Hw3e3U6WbakvGw2KDp0lPprTg2Pv50lC9ghFsLik1JQ3cvpM5iRQw6
D: O8S3+2CSto3VVigCa7/Ck2rtHauOCNOUAMY9KfiAyDAfv9lLC2MzrfVEk0po2p8mrQh+le9RwQKI
D: gLJp+G/yJEgIKootISf1HZ0uyGOWy2iqLygaaRd4C8zqB6kMNb2Pvo76DHfopE/GkU0rqFQe/HMh
D: aJx5whlsgY2UQU8dHO28LKcz6HRyl+4WvObwWpmhGAXJDFfTMHsIgsSQekzfVkQbYk9INuXbxQID
D: AQABo4IB2zCCAdcwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMCBggqgw4DAwQB
D: ATAPBgNVHSMECDAGgARbanQRMB0GA1UdDgQWBBSg7xyKYXvCr6OCr5zQ/5c0JN4I0zBeBgNVHSAE
D: VzBVMFMGByqDDgMDAgQwSDAhBggrBgEFBQcCARYVaHR0cDovL3BraS5nb3Yua3ovY3BzMCMGCCsG
D: AQUFBwICMBcMFWh0dHA6Ly9wa2kuZ292Lmt6L2NwczBWBgNVHR8ETzBNMEugSaBHhiFodHRwOi8v
D: Y3JsLnBraS5nb3Yua3ovbmNhX3JzYS5jcmyGImh0dHA6Ly9jcmwxLnBraS5nb3Yua3ovbmNhX3Jz
D: YS5jcmwwWgYDVR0uBFMwUTBPoE2gS4YjaHR0cDovL2NybC5wa2kuZ292Lmt6L25jYV9kX3JzYS5j
D: cmyGJGh0dHA6Ly9jcmwxLnBraS5nb3Yua3ovbmNhX2RfcnNhLmNybDBiBggrBgEFBQcBAQRWMFQw
D: LgYIKwYBBQUHMAKGImh0dHA6Ly9ASDFAWEQvbmNhX3JzYS5jZXIwIgYIKwYBBQUH
D: MAGGFmh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLnBraS5nb3Yua3owDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggIBAIxnLTs4soGhmZ6s
D: AM3JB1Xu3n6+RfuXQ1nFit2wAjFU0Ptflual5nulwcAMFXnj/9A+irXEOcBWaL8vMCd4OuI49wwr
D: +QVGErNp5t3zf8m9Z7ZKkzTtrKSE9JG4hz+URnS+N2DPl/Z+uD+2SdsILuseEKHwPitio9FtYDIL
D: RGRUX9LgQfYBl7c9Kjw3+zRgvGhB4NB+KwP7I1g8QB0OBj5B6GyhKN6QaezNAdwu/kO/xsExUyPP
D: DUlJ3WZG601ngrXABmyPSSgQOagC9EGDayfBlh9cZ/tEKdCwooR2IEVskuhm4JGGeOPKoUebp9pM
D: GUXhiVFdOx7SBAvwyI4AlK8bzVvKHGFczQiwikYZ0AKqD+oK4v/7ILOFZdbTcDZz5OA/MuqKo06S
D: 7nbl89fn4qyhWSvQLwkeWQu5z2elqzgnT19wE8rUC7Q+lsX/xikKkBGweAZT4wYShB5x8opCnRfL
D: sLlo1Rs0VRN16U9EmcgWy4mP5o+QuHWAJyUiYy69WumTjQyvz5ss/vJoLsqzPl0s8uW5bQkg2OXC
D: O/MFXxnc1k7n81RzRbNx+AIn8B8f8W6qfOZ3ighgSw8hweIvtMjtN9xKYY+DRH781QeSVFfb3uUg
D: VEByOAuXc1U+F/v6TFh5DEZZaVRQrIT6OFAf2RHRVlJognrtVyK+7Dr3C0Hi
D: </ds:X509Certificate>
D: </ds:X509Data>
D: </ds:KeyInfo>
D: </ds:Signature></APRequest>
D: --> END POST (3586-byte body)
D: <-- 200 OK http://url (259ms)
```

Is it possible now copy logs without tags like D:, I:? Or is it possible print logs in single line when using retrofit with okhttp3?

Comment: use [stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) you can copy it from chrome browser

Comment: Thank you, it was very useful!

Comment: I just run on debug mode then use : copy value from the breakpoint

Comment: @LinhNguyen good approach, I have not thought of it before, but it needs attaching debugger, so i decided to use stetho, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot 3rd party lib for analysing (Intercepting) network request

if using okhttp as base

1. [stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/)
2. [chuck](https://github.com/jgilfelt/chuck)
3. [okhttp-logging-interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor)
4. [LoggingInterceptor](https://github.com/ihsanbal/LoggingInterceptor)

in your case you can use this [LoggingInterceptor](https://github.com/ihsanbal/LoggingInterceptor)

Comment: Just now I have tried Logging interceptor, but could not copy request from log cat, but when using stetho i could see from chrome and copy it. Thank you